# I am not able to capture all search result links and description even though i am using correct className

Tags: xpath, selenium, automation, selector

I want to capture all search result links (search engine: http://search.yahoo.com) and summary from the result page. ClassName of Link is `'yschttl spt'` and className for summary is **`'abstr'`**

Source Code Looks like below for Link and summary.

Link:

```
<a id="yui_3_3_0_1_1301085039901361" dirtyhref="http://search.yahoo.com/r/_ylt=A0oG7m9u.4xNvWYA7N5XNyoA;_ylu=X3oDMTE2ZXNhNjRzBHNlYwNzcgRwb3MDMgRjb2xvA2FjMgR2dGlkA01TWUMwMDFfMTc5/SIG=11stois8r/EXP=1301106638/**http%3a//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pune,_India" class="yschttl spt" href="http://search.yahoo.com/r/_ylt=A0oG7m9u.4xNvWYA7N5XNyoA;_ylu=X3oDMTE2ZXNhNjRzBHNlYwNzcgRwb3MDMgRjb2xvA2FjMgR2dGlkA01TWUMwMDFfMTc5/SIG=11stois8r/EXP=1301106638/**http%3a//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pune,_India" data-bns="API" data-bk="5096.1"><b>Pune</b> - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia</a>`
```

Summary Div:

```
<div id="yui_3_3_0_1_1301085039901338" class="abstr"><b id="yui_3_3_0_1_1301085039901337">Pune</b> is undoubtedly a great place to eat. Fergusson <b id="yui_3_3_0_1_1301085039901352">College</b> <b>Road</b> is full of budget eateries serving delicous hot food at nominal charges. For a range of multi-cuisine ...</div>
```

I am using below line of code to capture both (link and summary).

```
final List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.className("yschttl spt")); 
final List<WebElement> linksSummary = driver.findElements(By.className("abstr"));
```

But now working at all.

I also tried using below XPaths for Link:

`//a[starts-with(@id, 'yui_')]`

`//a[@data-bns='API']`

I cannot use ID as  whole because that ID number is not same for all search result links.

Nothing is working. Please help.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure there isn't any default namespace declaration?

Comment: @Alejandro: I didn't get you. I just started learning, so can you please tell me in detail. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't use selenium 2.0 but when I tried `//a[@class='yschttl spt']` in Firefox XPath Checker, I got to see all 10 results in page. I am soon to begin with Selenium 2.0, may be I could try then...

Comment: Very strange!! When I am using `By.className("yschttl spt")` - it is not working but when I used as XPath it is returning correct result. thank you.. but now My question is - why if is not working with `By.className()` ? :(

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is that you are not correctly asking for a classname. The instance of `class="yschttl spt"` says that the element may be identified by *two* class names, `yschttl` or `spt`. It does **not** say that the classname is `yschttl spt` so asking for `By.className("yschttl spt")` will always fail.

Note that the reason the XPath suggested by @Tarun works is that XPath has **no** notion of what an HTML class name is or should be. In XPath, `@class` simply specifies the name of an attribute--with **no** underlying semantics.

Further, note that a class name may not contain spaces. For more details about specifying class names, see the HTML [class](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#adef-class) attribute specification.

Comment: Ok. But then how can we specify class name if class name has space if one does not want to use XPath?

Comment: Again, let me emphasize that class names do _not_ have spaces; you have two distinct class names, so with the `By.className` syntax you may specify either `By.className("yschttl")` or `By.className("spt")`.

Comment: But class name is 'yschttl spt' so my question is.. when there is a space in class name how do we have to use in `By.className()` method? Sorry but still i didn't get you.

Comment: Since the class **attribute** specifies two class **names** (_yschttl_ and _spt_) you can only use `By.className` to pick one or the other. If you really need to find the element with both class names, you will need to first find the element with one of the names then test it to see if its class attribute also contains the other. So it is not terribly elegant. It might be simpler to use XPath to match the attribute value, but there are pitfalls with that approach, too: eg. class="yschttl spt" and class="spt yschttl" are clearly different attributes but they specify the same class names.

Comment: I got your point but still i am having confusion. `"yschttl spt"` is a single class name. So you mean class name having space cannot be used in `By.className()` and I have to always use `By.xpath()`?